# How to filter data of a List using Checkboxes in Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to implement a function in Expo to filter my data using checkboxes. I have already completed my checkboxes and designed them accordingly. The data to be filtered is pulled from the Firebase database and displayed in the form of a list on my page. I have also created a button for the filtering, which is used so that when a user clicks this button, the filtering takes place according to the selection of the respective boxes. Attached is a picture that shows what has already been implemented and below the code for it. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this, as I am relatively new to React Native and have not found anything in this regard.

Thanks in advance

[Anbieterliste-Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWvxO.jpg)

```
function MyCheckbox() {
  const [checked, onChange] = useState(false);

  function onCheckmarkPress() {
    onChange(!checked);
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.checkboxBase, checked && styles.checkboxChecked]}
      onPress={onCheckmarkPress}>
      {checked && <Ionicons name="checkmark" size={18} color="white" />}
    </Pressable>
  );
}

export default function Anbieter({ route, navigation }) {

  //CONSTS WHICH WE GOT FROM THE HOMEPAGE AND DECLARATION 
  const { latitude, longitude, address } = route.params;
  var getLat = latitude;
  var getLong = longitude;
  var getAddress = JSON.stringify(address);
  const [restaurentList, setRestaurentList] = useState()
  const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState()
  const [ranges, setRanges] = useState(1)
  const [showRange, setShowRange] = useState(false)


  // THIS IS A LIST WHICH DISPLAY ALL RESTAURANTS BY GETTING DATA IN PARAMS IN NAME OF DATA

  const ListButton = ({ title, data }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Produktubersicht', { data }) }} style={[styles.itemContainer]}>
        <Image source={{ uri: data.anbieterImg }} style={{ width: '90%', marginLeft: '5%', height: 160 }} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20 }}>{data.firmenname}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20, width: '90%' }}>Adresse:
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{data.adresse}</Text>
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20, width: '90%' }}>Kategorie:
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{data.kategorie}</Text>
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

  }


  // THIS FUNCTION IS USE TO CALL ALL RESTAURANT FROM FIREBASE DATABASE 
  const getRestaurents = async () => {
    let arr = []
    // THIS IS FIREBASE API ALL DATA IS COMING FROM FIREBASE
    var ar = await firebase.database().ref("/anbieter/").once("child_added", snapshot => {
      var obj = snapshot.val();
      obj.id = snapshot.key;

      arr.push(obj);
    });
    // ALL DATA OF RESTAURANT IS STORING IN STATE HERE THEN FROM HERE ALL DATA WILL DISPLAY 
    setRestaurentList(arr)
  }
  var users = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  useEffect(() => {

    // WE CALL GET RESTAURANTS API HERE BECAUSE THIS USEEFFECT JUST CALL ONCE WHEN COMPONENT RENDER 
    console.log(users, 'users');
    getRestaurents()

  }, []);



  // THIS IS SIGN OUT BUTTON , WHEN USER CLICK FOR SIGNOUT THEN IT ASKS WHETHER HE/SHE IS SURE TO DO SO 
  const signOutFunc = async () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Ausloggen?",
      "Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie sich ausloggen möchten?",
      [
        {
          text: "Bestätigen", onPress: async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userName')
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('order')
            firebase.auth().signOut();
            navigation.navigate('Homepage');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: "Abbrechen",
          style: "cancel"
        }
      ]
    );


  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {/* THIS IS THE PART OF ICON WHERE LOGIN , SIGNOUT , Bestellverlauf AND  Warenkorb ICON ARE HERE */}
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginRight: 5, marginVertical: 10 }}>
          {users ?
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { signOutFunc() }}>
              <Entypo name="log-out" size={30} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            : null}
          {users ?
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Bestellverlauf') }} style={{ marginRight: 20 }}>
                <Fontisto name="prescription" size={30} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Warenkorb') }}>
                <Feather name="shopping-bag" size={30} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            :
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Anmelden') }}>
              <FontAwesome5 name="user" size={30} color="black" />
              <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Registration/Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.textFirst}>Ermittelte Adresse:</Text>
        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', width: '90%' }}>
          <Text style={{ marginBottom: 15, marginTop: 10, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>{getAddress} </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setShowRange(!showRange) }}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="filter-plus" size={30} color="grey" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/* THIS IS RANGE SLIDER FOR SORTING ALL RESTAURANTS */}
        {showRange ?

          <View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> Entfernung festlegen!</Text>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%' }}> {Math.round(ranges)} km</Text>
            </View>
            <Slider maximumValue={100} style={{ width: '90%', marginLeft: '5%', marginTop: 10, }} value={ranges} onValueChange={(e) => setRanges(e)} />
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 10, }}>Filterung nach Kategorie</Text>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Backware</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Bioprodukte</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Feinkost</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Griechische Spezialitäten</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Molkerei</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <MyCheckbox />
                <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>Türkische Spezialitäten</Text>
              </View>
              <Button title="Filter anwenden..." color='#5271FF'/>
            </View>
          </View>
          : null
        }

        <Text style={styles.textSecond}>Sie können gerne die Filterfunktion verwenden, indem Sie oben auf den Symbol klicken...</Text>
        {restaurentList && restaurentList.map((val, i) => {

          return <ListButton key={i} title={val.firmenname} data={val} />
        })}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to avoid duplication of code is to create a filterList array and create dynamic filters component.

I modified your code, check the comments for the explanation.

```
function MyCheckbox({addFilter, removeFilter, filterIndex}) { // ADD THIS PROPS TO ADD AND REMOVE FILTERS
  const [checked, onChange] = useState(false);

  function onCheckmarkPress() {
    onChange(!checked);
    checked ? addFilter(filterIndex) : removeFilter(filterIndex)
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.checkboxBase, checked && styles.checkboxChecked]}
      onPress={onCheckmarkPress}>
      {checked && <Ionicons name="checkmark" size={18} color="white" />}
    </Pressable>
  );
}

export default function Anbieter({ route, navigation }) {

  //CONSTS WHICH WE GOT FROM THE HOMEPAGE AND DECLARATION 
  const { latitude, longitude, address } = route.params;
  var getLat = latitude;
  var getLong = longitude;
  var getAddress = JSON.stringify(address);
  const [restaurentList, setRestaurentList] = useState()
  const [filteredRestaurantList, setFilteredRestaurentList] = useState() // <-- ADD THIS STATE TO KEEP TRACK OF THE FILTERED LIST TO DISPLAY
  const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState()
  const [ranges, setRanges] = useState(1)
  const [showRange, setShowRange] = useState(false)
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]) // <-- ADD THIS STATE TO KEEP TRACK OF THE FILTERS SELECTED
  
  const filterList = ["Backware", "Bioprodukte", "Feinkost", "Griechische Spezialitäten"] // <--- CREATE A FILTER ARRAY
  
  const addFilter = (filterIndex) => { // <-- FUNCTION ADD FILTER
    setFilters([...filters, filterList[filterIndex]])
  }
  
  const removeFilter = (filterIndex) => { // <-- FUNCTION REMOVE FILTER
    const index = filters.indexOf(filterList[filterIndex]);
    const newFilters = [...filters];
    newFilters.splice(index, 1)
    setFilters(newFilters)
  }


  // THIS IS A LIST WHICH DISPLAY ALL RESTAURANTS BY GETTING DATA IN PARAMS IN NAME OF DATA

  const ListButton = ({ title, data }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Produktubersicht', { data }) }} style={[styles.itemContainer]}>
        <Image source={{ uri: data.anbieterImg }} style={{ width: '90%', marginLeft: '5%', height: 160 }} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20 }}>{data.firmenname}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20, width: '90%' }}>Adresse:
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{data.adresse}</Text>
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", marginLeft: 20, width: '90%' }}>Kategorie:
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{data.kategorie}</Text>
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

  }


  // THIS FUNCTION IS USE TO CALL ALL RESTAURANT FROM FIREBASE DATABASE 
  const getRestaurents = async () => {
    let arr = []
    // THIS IS FIREBASE API ALL DATA IS COMING FROM FIREBASE
    var ar = await firebase.database().ref("/anbieter/").once("child_added", snapshot => {
      var obj = snapshot.val();
      obj.id = snapshot.key;
      
      arr.push(obj);
    });
    // ALL DATA OF RESTAURANT IS STORING IN STATE HERE THEN FROM HERE ALL DATA WILL DISPLAY 
    setRestaurentList(arr)
    setFilteredRestaurentList(arr)
  }
  var users = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  useEffect(() => {

    // WE CALL GET RESTAURANTS API HERE BECAUSE THIS USEEFFECT JUST CALL ONCE WHEN COMPONENT RENDER 
    console.log(users, 'users');
    getRestaurents()

  }, []);
  
   useEffect(() => { // <--- ADD THIS TO UPDATE THE FILTER RESTAURANT LIST EVERY TIME THAT THE FILTER ARRAY CHANGE
    const rList = [...restaurentList];
    if (filters.length) { 
            const filteredList = rList.filter(r => {
        const toAdd = filters.indexOf(r.category) 
        if (toAdd !== -1) {
            return r
        }
        })
        setFilteredRestaurentList(filteredList)
    }else { // <-- IF THERE ARE NO FILTER; RESET TO ORIGINAL LIST
        setFilteredRestaurentList(rList)
    }


  }, [filters]);

 

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {/* THIS IS THE PART OF ICON WHERE LOGIN , SIGNOUT , Bestellverlauf AND  Warenkorb ICON ARE HERE */}
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginRight: 5, marginVertical: 10 }}>
          {users ?
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { signOutFunc() }}>
              <Entypo name="log-out" size={30} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            : null}
          {users ?
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Bestellverlauf') }} style={{ marginRight: 20 }}>
                <Fontisto name="prescription" size={30} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Warenkorb') }}>
                <Feather name="shopping-bag" size={30} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            :
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Anmelden') }}>
              <FontAwesome5 name="user" size={30} color="black" />
              <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Registration/Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.textFirst}>Ermittelte Adresse:</Text>
        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', width: '90%' }}>
          <Text style={{ marginBottom: 15, marginTop: 10, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>{getAddress} </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setShowRange(!showRange) }}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="filter-plus" size={30} color="grey" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/* THIS IS RANGE SLIDER FOR SORTING ALL RESTAURANTS */}
        {showRange ?

          <View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> Entfernung festlegen!</Text>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%' }}> {Math.round(ranges)} km</Text>
            </View>
            <Slider maximumValue={100} style={{ width: '90%', marginLeft: '5%', marginTop: 10, }} value={ranges} onValueChange={(e) => setRanges(e)} />
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: '3%', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 10, }}>Filterung nach Kategorie</Text>
                  {filterList.map((filterItem, index) => (
                  <View 
                    key={index}
                    style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                    <MyCheckbox 
                        addFilter={addFilter} // <-- ADD THIS PROP 
                        removeFilter={removeFilter} // <-- ADD THIS PROP 
                        filterIndex={index} // <-- ADD THIS PROP 
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.checkboxLabel}>filterItem</Text>
                  </View>
                  ))}
              <Button title="Filter anwenden..." color='#5271FF'/>
            </View>
          </View>
          : null
        }

        <Text style={styles.textSecond}>Sie können gerne die Filterfunktion verwenden, indem Sie oben auf den Symbol klicken...</Text>
        {filteredRestaurantList && filteredRestaurantList.map((val, i) => {

          return <ListButton key={i} title={val.firmenname} data={val} />
        })}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have now changed my code but I get the following error message now: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]'). Do you know what I can do if I get this error? Thanks in advance